# Can't Mount Remote Share From RHEL 6

Tags: mount, rhel5, ext3, ext4

I'm trying to upgrade some Linux systems to RHEL 6, but I cannot mount the home directories. I'm using EXT4 for the RHEL 6 system and EXT3 on the RHEL 5 server, which I'm mounting the directory from. I can't just use the mount command; I have to specify `-t ext3`, and when I do it says, "Special device (server name and mount point) does not exist". It works just fine from all the RHEL 5 machines, just not from this new RHEL 6 machine.

I just rebuilt the machine and used EXT3 as the file system type this time just to test. It produced the same results: It won't mount.

Comment: You need to clarify if the file system is remote or not. If it's a directly attached device then you mount with ext3/ext4/reiserfs/whatever, if it's somewhere else on the network then you mount is using the type of network file system it's exported with, eg: smb, cifs, nfs.

Comment: I tried -t NFS it says wrong FS type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a configuration error on my part why it wouldnt mount, but ext4 is backward compatible

Comment: Can you tell us what the configuration error was please ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert that ext3 to ext4

`# umount /dev/sdbx`

`# tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index /dev/sdbx`

`# fsck -pf /dev/sdbx`

`# mount /dev/sdbx`

`#vi /etc/fstab`

`#reboot`

Comment: Are you serious? Everything i read says it is backward compatible http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4